# How to use group by clause to optimise stored procedure that contains multiple subquery?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-performance

I have a stored procedure that fetches 60 records and took 7-8 seconds, hint to improve stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Exat_ProductionLog]
    @Condition varchar(max) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC ('declare @startedstatus uniqueidentifier =  (select [dbo].[GetMasterSatusByName](''WIP''))
    DECLARE @Clarification uniqueidentifier =  (select [dbo].[GetMasterSatusByName](''OnHold''))
    DECLARE @Completed uniqueidentifier =  (select [dbo].[GetMasterSatusByName](''Completed''))

    SELECT A.*,Total =  A.NoofAccounts 
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             J.ReceivedOn ReceivedOn,
             CONVERT(varchar(10), J.ReceivedOn, 20) ReceivedDate,
             (SELECT TOP 1 
                  Convert(varchar(10), AssignedDate, 20) 
              FROM AssignedCase 
              WHERE CaseID = AC.CaseID 
              ORDER BY AssignedDate DESC) AssignedDate,
             UF.Name Facility, UT.Name [Type],
             C.CaseNumber Batch, C.ACHA ACHA, J.Noofaccounts,
             [BatchStartdate] = Convert(varchar(10), (select top 1 StatusOnUTC from log_CaseStatus where CaseID = C.CaseID and StatusID=@startedstatus order by StatusOnUTC asc),20),
             [AccountProcessed]=(select COUNT(*) from Account ACC inner join log_AccountStatus LA on LA.AccountID = ACC.AccountId where ACC.CaseId = C.CaseID and LA.StatusID=@Completed),
             [ClarificationLog] =(select dbo.[Exat_GetClarificationCount](C.CaseID)),
             [Status] = (select Name from [MasterStatus] where StatusId = (select [dbo].[GetStatusIdByCaseID](C.CaseID))),
             [Reviewer] =(select SUBSTRING((SELECT ( '','' + DisplayName)  from um_user where UserID in
                 (select UserID from AssignedCase where  CaseID = C.CaseID and [Type] in(''DC'',''Demo'',''Charges''))FOR XML PATH('''')), 2, 1000)),
                [Auditor] =(select SUBSTRING((SELECT ( '','' + DisplayName)  from um_user where UserID in
                 (select ValidatedBy from Account where Validated = 1 and CaseID = C.CaseID)FOR XML PATH('''')), 2, 1000)),
                [AuditCount] = (select Count(*) from Account where  CaseID = C.CaseID),
                [Errors] = (select Count(*) from log_AccountError LA inner join Account ACO on ACO.AccountID = LA.AccountID where  ACO.CaseID = C.CaseID)

     from [Job] J inner join [Case] C on J.JobID = C.JobID
     inner join log_casestatus lcs on lcs.caseid=c.caseid
     inner join [Account] A on C.CaseID = A.CaseID inner join [AssignedCase] AC on AC.CaseID = C.CaseID
     inner join um_Facility UF on UF.FacilityID = J.FacilityID
     inner join um_Type UT on UT.TypeID = J.TypeID
     inner join log_AccountStatus LA on LA.AccountID = A.AccountID)A  where 1=1 '+@Condition+'')


End
```

any clue for improving performance of the mentioned SP ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to add an execution plan of the main query

Comment: In execution plan main select A.* , ...... took 99% cost. all other take 1%.

Comment: before looking at performance improvement I'd recommend you try and stop using EXEC and convert to sp_ExecuteSQL. EXEC is prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: try and strip back the dynamic SQL to a specific  query that you can run on your system. The execution plan should then provide more specific information.

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-an-execution-plan-in-sql-server - links in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replace your stored procedure by code not repeatable, and a have used your tables join only one time. Try something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Exat_ProductionLog]
    @Condition varchar(max) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC ('declare @startedstatus uniqueidentifier =  (select [dbo].[GetMasterSatusByName](''WIP''))

    DECLARE @Clarification uniqueidentifier =  (select [dbo].[GetMasterSatusByName](''OnHold''))
    DECLARE @Completed uniqueidentifier =  (select [dbo].[GetMasterSatusByName](''Completed''))

    SELECT A.*,Total =  A.NoofAccounts 
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             J.ReceivedOn,
             CONVERT(varchar(10), J.ReceivedOn, 20) ReceivedDate,
             ASSC.AssignedDate,
             UF.Name Facility, UT.Name [Type],
             C.CaseNumber Batch, C.ACHA , J.Noofaccounts ,
             BSD.BatchStartdate,
             LSS.AccountProcessed,
             [ClarificationLog] =(select count(distinct LAS.AccountID ) from log_AccountStatus LAS where A.AccountID = LAS.AccountID and LAS.StatusID=@Clarification) ,                 
             [Status] = (select Name from [MasterStatus] where StatusId = (select [dbo].[GetStatusIdByCaseID](C.CaseID))),
             [Reviewer] = (select SUBSTRING((SELECT ( '','' + DisplayName)  
                           from um_user where UserID in
                 (select UserID from AssignedCase where  CaseID = C.CaseID and [Type] in(''DC'',''Demo'',''Charges''))FOR XML PATH('''')), 2, 1000)),

             [Auditor] =(select SUBSTRING((SELECT ( '','' + DisplayName)  from um_user where UserID in
                 (select ValidatedBy from Account where Validated = 1 and CaseID = C.CaseID)FOR XML PATH('''')), 2, 1000)),

             [AuditCount] = (select Count(*) from Account where  CaseID = C.CaseID),

             ERR.[Errors]

             from [Job] J 
             inner join [Case] C on J.JobID = C.JobID
             inner join [Account] A on C.CaseID = A.CaseID 
             inner join um_Facility UF on UF.FacilityID = J.FacilityID
             inner join um_Type UT on UT.TypeID = J.TypeID

             cross apply
             (
              select top 1 Convert(varchar(10), AC.AssignedDate, 20) as AssignedDate from AssignedCase AC
              where AC.CaseID = C.CaseID
              ORDER BY AC.AssignedDate DESC 
             ) ASSC

             cross apply
             (
              select Convert(varchar(10), min(case when lcs.StatusID=@startedstatus then lcs.StatusOnUTC else null end) ,20)  BatchStartdate  from log_CaseStatus lcs
              where lcs.CaseID = C.CaseID
             ) BSD

             cross apply
             (
              select sum(case when LA.StatusID=@Completed then 1 else 0 end) AccountProcessed   from log_AccountStatus la
              where LA.AccountID = A.AccountID
             ) LSS

             cross apply
             (
              select count(*) as [Errors]  from log_AccountError lae
              where A.AccountID = LAE.AccountID
             ) ERR

        )A  
        where 1=1 '+@Condition+'')


End
```

Comment: i have modified my query with your replace code of proc storage ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply , here i found all record but i want record only batch wise , our case table has all the batch details , inside batch we have multiple Account, i mean One Batch can hold many Account, You noticed that our 4 column has just count. if i want to use group by clause , it is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fresh copy that removes the function.

```
DECLARE @Condition varchar(max) = --insert value here
declare @startedstatus uniqueidentifier =  --insert value here
DECLARE @Clarification uniqueidentifier =  --insert value here
DECLARE @Completed uniqueidentifier =  --insert value here
declare @Clarification uniqueidentifier = (select StatusID from MasterStatus where Name=('OnHold')  --remove this from funtion so it only executes once

SELECT DISTINCT 
    J.ReceivedOn ReceivedOn
    ,CONVERT(varchar(10), J.ReceivedOn, 20)  AS ReceivedDate
    ,UF.Name Facility
    ,UT.Name [Type]
    ,C.CaseNumber Batch
    ,C.ACHA ACHA 
    ,J.Noofaccounts

    ,[AssignedDate] = (SELECT TOP 1 Convert(varchar(10), AssignedDate, 20) 
        FROM AssignedCase 
        WHERE CaseID = AC.CaseID 
        ORDER BY AssignedDate DESC)

    ,[BatchStartdate] = Convert(varchar(10), (select top 1 StatusOnUTC 
                                        from log_CaseStatus 
                                        where CaseID = C.CaseID 
                                            and StatusID=@startedstatus 
                                        order by StatusOnUTC asc),20)

    ,[AccountProcessed]=(select COUNT(*) 
                        from Account ACC inner join log_AccountStatus LA on LA.AccountID = ACC.AccountId 
                        where ACC.CaseId = C.CaseID and LA.StatusID=@Completed)

    --,[ClarificationLog] =(select dbo.[Exat_GetClarificationCount](C.CaseID))
    --REMOVE FUNCTION FROM STORED PROCEDURE
    ,[ClarificationLog] =(select COUNT(DISTINCT LA.AccountID)
                            from log_AccountStatus LA 
                            inner join Account A 
                            on A.AccountID = LA.AccountID 
                            where LA.StatusID=@Clarification 
                            and A.CaseId = C.CaseId)


    ,[Status] = (select Name from [MasterStatus] where StatusId = (select [dbo].[GetStatusIdByCaseID](C.CaseID)))
    ,[Reviewer] =(select SUBSTRING((SELECT ( ',' + DisplayName)  from um_user where UserID in
                    (select UserID from AssignedCase where  CaseID = C.CaseID and [Type] in('DC','Demo','Charges'))FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 1000))
    ,[Auditor] =(select SUBSTRING((SELECT ( ',' + DisplayName)  from um_user where UserID in
                    (select ValidatedBy from Account where Validated = 1 and CaseID = C.CaseID)FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 1000))
    ,[AuditCount] = (select Count(*) from Account where  CaseID = C.CaseID)
    ,[Errors] = (select Count(*) from log_AccountError LA inner join Account ACO on ACO.AccountID = LA.AccountID where  ACO.CaseID = C.CaseID)

from 
    [Job] J 
        inner join [Case] C 
            on 
            J.JobID = C.JobID
        inner join log_casestatus lcs 
            on 
            lcs.caseid=c.caseid
        inner join [Account] A 
            on 
            C.CaseID = A.CaseID 
        inner join [AssignedCase] AC 
            on 
            AC.CaseID = C.CaseID
        inner join um_Facility UF 
            on 
            UF.FacilityID = J.FacilityID
        inner join um_Type UT 
            on 
            UT.TypeID = J.TypeID
        inner join log_AccountStatus LA 
            on LA.AccountID = A.AccountID
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks ,But my boss suggested to me replace subquery use group by clause , because our 4 column just count the records from different tables by inner join, how to achieve?

Comment: The execution plan will tell you which Sub Queries are the most expensive  and help you decide which ones to tackle with GROUP BYs first.

Comment: ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Exat_GetClarificationCount](CaseId variable)
RETURNS INT  
AS  
BEGIN  
declare @ClarifyCount int
 
 declare Clarification uniqueidentifier =  (select StatusID from MasterStatus where Name=('OnHold'))
 declare AccountDetails Table(AccountId uniqueidentifier) 
 insert into AccountDetails  
  select distinct LA.AccountID from log_AccountStatus LA inner join Account A on A.AccountID = LA.AccountID
  where LA.StatusID=Clarification and A.CaseId = CaseId
  set ClarifyCount = (select Count(*) from AccountDetails)
  Return ClarifyCount END

Comment: without visibility of your data, it's very difficult to help you with your GROUP BY. As you get into Grouping values from multiple tables you can find yourself double-counting values in some tables. The fact your query requires a DISTINCT command indicates that such a problem may exist.

Comment: when i remove above function query executes fast , how can i improve ....

Comment: I've rewritten the answer to remove the function and make it part of the SP